# Wordpress - Custom Registration Form, Redirect After

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, redirect, registration

I have a custom registration form.   I am trying to redirect users to a specific page after they've registered, but the methods I have tried have not worked, here is my code - how can I get a redirection after a user has registered?:

EDIT: (a jQuery or Javascript solutuion for this would be acceptable too)

```
<?php
/* Load registration file. */
require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/registration.php' );

/* If user registered, input info. */
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'adduser' ) {
    $user_pass = wp_generate_password();
    $userdata = array(
        'user_pass' => esc_attr( $_POST['user_pass'] ),
        'user_login' => esc_attr( $_POST['user_name'] ),
        'user_email' => esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ),
    );

    if ( !$userdata['user_login'] )
        $error = __('A username is required for registration.', 'frontendprofile');
    elseif ( username_exists($userdata['user_login']) )
        $error = __('Sorry, that username already exists!', 'frontendprofile');
    elseif ( !is_email($userdata['user_email'], true) )
        $error = __('You must enter a valid email address.', 'frontendprofile');
    elseif ( email_exists($userdata['user_email']) )
        $error = __('Sorry, that email address is already used!', 'frontendprofile');

    else{
        $new_user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
        update_usermeta( $new_user, 'fullname', esc_attr( $_POST['fullname']  ) );
        update_usermeta( $new_user, 'publication', esc_attr( $_POST['publication']  ) );
        update_usermeta( $new_user, 'usertype', esc_attr( $_POST['usertype']  ) );
        wp_new_user_notification($new_user, $user_pass);
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.google.com' );
    }
}

?>

<form method="post" id="adduser" class="user-forms" action="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
  <p class="form-usertype">
  <strong>TYPE</strong>
    <?php $usertype = get_the_author_meta( 'usertype', $current_user->ID ); ?>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input class="radio" value="Media" name="usertype" <?php if ($_POST['usertype'] == 'Media' ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php }?> type="radio" />
      <span><?php _e('Media', 'frontendprofile'); ?></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input class="radio" value="Freelance"  name="usertype" <?php if ($_POST['usertype'] == 'Freelance'  ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php }?> type="radio" />
      <span><?php _e('Freelance',  'frontendprofile'); ?></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input class="radio" value="Student" name="usertype" <?php if ($_POST['usertype'] == 'Student' ) { ?>checked="checked"<?php }?> type="radio" />
      <span><?php _e('Student', 'frontendprofile'); ?></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </p>
  <!-- .form-usertype -->

  <p class="form-username">
    <strong>FULL NAME</strong>
    <input class="text-input" name="user_name" type="text" id="user_name" value="<?php if ( $error ) echo wp_specialchars( $_POST['user_name'], 1 ); ?>" />
  </p>
  <!-- .form-username -->

  <p class="form-email">
    <strong>E-MAIL</strong>
    <input class="text-input" name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?php if ( $error ) echo wp_specialchars( $_POST['email'], 1 ); ?>" />
  </p>
  <!-- .form-email -->

  <p class="form-password">
  <strong>CONFIRM E-MAIL</strong>
  <input type="text" name="user_pass" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" tabindex="10" />
  </p>

  <p class="form-publication">
  <strong>MEDIA OUTLET</strong>
    <input class="text-input" name="publication" type="text" id="publication" value="<?php if ( $error ) echo wp_specialchars( $_POST['publication'], 1 ); ?>"/>
  </p>
  <!-- .form-publication -->

  <p class="form-submit"> <?php echo $referer; ?>
    <input name="adduser" type="submit" id="addusersub" class="submit button" value="<?php if ( current_user_can( 'create_users' ) ) _e('Add User', 'frontendprofile'); else _e('Register', 'frontendprofile'); ?>" />
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'add-user' ) ?>
    <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="adduser" />
  </p>
  <!-- .form-submit -->

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("input[name$='usertype']").click(function(){

  var radio_value = $(this).val();

  if(radio_value=='Media') {
     $("p.form-publication").show();
  }
  else if(radio_value=='Student') {
    $("p.form-publication").hide();
  }
  else if(radio_value=='Freelance') {
    $("p.form-publication").hide();
  }
  }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is not working? You have a redirect to google it doesnt redirect?

Comment: Yes the redirect does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pluggin is not respecting the expected action hook format that you'd normally use. What you have to do here is to hook two different functions for your pluggin.

One will draw the pluggin when necessary, using a shortcode for example.

The other will hook into the early processing of wordpress to actually do what it's got to do such as adding a user. Then, if you use wp_redirect it will allow you to redirect before any output is sent to the browser.

For example, in my pluggins, i use the hooks:

```
add_action('init', 'my_function_to_process');
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_function_to_draw');
```

And i create those two functions to do what they have to do in my pluggin's file.

You might want to check out the hooks database api for more information on hooks:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Good luck

**EDIT**

Just change:

```
wp_redirect( 'http://www.google.com' );
```

For:

```
?><script>window.href.location = "http://www.google.com";</script><?php exit();
```

And you would be on your way to victory... It's ugly in terms of integration, i'd have done it with a pluggin but it should work fine...

Comment: Its not a plugin.  Its a front end registration form, allowing the registration to occur within the sites design rather than redirecting to the wp-login.php registration.  Not sure if this changes anything :)

Comment: Still changes everything, you must then find a way to include your code BEFORE the wordpress drawing starts to happen. If you processing code occurs after wordpress has started drawing, you can't redirect, because the headers are already sent... Sure it's not a pluggin, but you HAVE to find a way to load that processing code earlier. A pluggin wouldn't be a bad idea since pluggins are loaded early...

Comment: Is it not possible then to add jQuery or something after "submit" is pressed that says "after submit, send user to mywebpage.com" ?

Comment: Ok, well then this is a completly different procedure... WP_REDIRECT is the same as "header('location: http://newsiteaddress/');"... This operates on the server BEFORE the content is sent to the browser. If you want, you can do a javascript redirect using 'window.href.location = "http://newsiteaddress/";'. This can be output anywhere on the page, but if the user doesn't allow javascript redirects to happen he will stay on the page...

Comment: The website is already very javascript heavy so I believe a jQuery or JS solution would work.  Where would I need to insert this?